# Weird JSON output for filepaths

Tags: json, perl, cpan

I'm using JSON::XS, and I'm getting some weird output from an encoding of some file paths.

To create the output, I just call `encode_json` on some data that I get from calling a dir command from perl (using ``` `` ```). Which I save in an array.

I end up with a JSON string that looks like the following:

```
 "\"E: \\\\helm\\\\Layman1\\n\""
```

Where are the extra backslashes coming from?

Comment: They are here to make valid json.

Comment: Note that you started with `"E: \\helm\\Layman1\LF"` (quotes included, and `LF` represents a line feed), which is not a valid path on account of the quotes, the space, the extra slashes and the line feed. `E:\helm\Layman1` would be encoded as `"E:\\helm\\Layman1"` rather than `"\"E: \\\\helm\\\\Layman1\\n\""`

Comment: I'm not doing that. It's what perl makes of the output. In a terminal it doesn't look like that.

Comment: huh? Did Perl output `"\"E: \\\\helm\\\\Layman1\\n\""` to the terminal or did it output something else? Could you update your node with what was actually output?

Comment: I'm not decoding it back so I'm not concerned with that. I can clean it up as such. Out of curiosity how do you control this?

Comment: How do you control what?

Comment: Ok. Here's the flow: @arr = `dir whatever`; then json_encode @arr. What you're seeing is the result of json_encode

Comment: Well that's not true.

Comment: Do make your point clearer please.

Comment: That's clearly not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `\` character has special meaning in JSON. To represent one as data in JSON it must be expressed as an escape sequence: `\\`.